# Sketch Symbols - replacement sizes

Tags: sketch-app, symbols

In Sketch, how different do the artboard sizes need to be so they DO NOT show up as replacement options? For example, I have some symbols that are 200px x 48px and when I want to replace them, I also see other symbols that are 190px x 50px. Does anyone know what the threshold is for Sketch to think they're not the same?

Comment: How do you name your symbols? If you use a slash to divide your symbols into groups, it should show you the similarly named and sized symbols first. I just created a blank document with a test and the same is happening to me, while this never happened in old documents and still doesn't. Maybe it's a bug ('feature') from a new update?

Answer (score 1):

The symbols are normally managed by name. You can group the symbols by rename them as:

"200px/symbol_01","200px/symbol_02";

"190px/symbol_01","190px/symbol_02";

[image]

Then when you swapping symbols, you'll only see the 200px or 190px symbols in that group. Check the [official document](https://www.sketchapp.com/docs/symbols/organizing-symbols/) to learn more.